# No implementation for `T + T`

Tags: rust

In this following example:

```rust
trait AddStrategy<T> {
    fn do_calc(&mut self, a: T, b: T) -> &Adder<T>;
}
struct Adder<T> {
    val: T,
}

use std::ops::Add;
fn add<T: Add>(a: T, b: T) -> T::Output {
    a + b
}

impl<T> AddStrategy<T> for Adder<T> {
    fn do_calc(&mut self, a: T, b: T) -> &Adder<T> {
        let x = add(a, b); //<---error: no implementation for `T + T`
        self.val = x;
        self
    }
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `T` to `T`
  --> src/lib.rs:15:17
   |
9  | fn add<T: Add>(a: T, b: T) -> T::Output {
   |    ---    --- required by this bound in `add`
...
13 | impl<T> AddStrategy<T> for Adder<T> {
   |      - help: consider restricting this bound: `T: std::ops::Add`
14 |     fn do_calc(&mut self, a: T, b: T) -> &Adder<T> {
15 |         let x = add(a, b); //<---error: no implementation for `T + T`
   |                 ^^^ no implementation for `T + T`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `T`

error[E0277]: cannot add `T` to `T`
  --> src/lib.rs:15:17
   |
13 | impl<T> AddStrategy<T> for Adder<T> {
   |      - help: consider restricting this bound: `T: std::ops::Add`
14 |     fn do_calc(&mut self, a: T, b: T) -> &Adder<T> {
15 |         let x = add(a, b); //<---error: no implementation for `T + T`
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `T + T`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `T`
```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: T+T is a new smiley ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9a1bff63aae400b7a699d4f3b785f83 just listen what compiler tell you

Comment: _"= help: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `T`"_

Comment: _"- help: consider restricting this bound: `T: std::ops::Add`"_

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed your example so you can find your working solution in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04eeed8fb463e91c1a47d2f8cfc869ca).

While `fn add<T: Add>(a: T, b: T)` has the trait bound `Add` for type `T`,  `AddStrategy` which calls it does not have the same trait bound: anything  (sized) can be used by `AddStrategy`. Therefore the Rust compiler tells you "*I'm sorry, but you're trying to call `add` on something which isn't guaranteed to be add-able*".

So the first thing you have to do is to bound `AddStrategy` to `Add`:

```rust
trait AddStrategy<T: Add> { // <--- T: Add
}
```

And it sounds pretty good since `AddStrategy` is about to **add** values.

The same with trait implementation for `Adder`:

```rust
impl<T: Add> AddStrategy<T> for Adder<T> {  // <--- T: Add
```

Then you have to fix `Adder` because it's about to store the output from the `add` function which has type of `T::Output`, and `Output` is an item type of `Add` trait:

```rust
struct Adder<T: Add> {  // <--- Now Adder is aware about T characteristics
    val: T::Output,     // <--- so you can use `T::Output` from the `Add` trait
}
```

And so on: basically, define traits for types and it allows you to fix errors step by step until you make everything explicit.

An alternative (which doesn't seem useful here but there you go) is that instead of `Adder` being bound to `Add` you could implement `AddStrategy` *if and only if* `Adder` is working with `Add` values: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d83fd48f88eec68346a3d633e8a7f72c

Comment: Thank you very much for making it crystal clear. And also for showing the other way. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks to @Masklinn for editing my answer :)